# Remember selected day and show list after refresh

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I’ve a layout (Let’s call it WeekReservations) with different textview which represent the days of this month. For each day there’s a listview with reservations. The listview is for each day different. Also for each selected day you can make a reservation.

**First time landing on WeekReservations**

[image]
First time landing on this page won't show anything until you choose a day.

**After selecting a day**

[image]

Default, if I land on this page there are no selected days. Which means I can’t see a listview until I choose a day. When I make a reservation and submit it, I will be directed back to the WeekReservations page (to redirect them back, I’ve refreshed this page).

To do the refresh I used these line of codes:

```
var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(WeekViewActivity));
            intent.SetFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            StartActivity (intent);
```

All the data will be updated correctly. Until here it works all fine.

But the problem is, when I’m directed back to the WeekReservations page, I won’t be seeing the day with the list of reservations where I made my reservation. I need to choose the day again (the day where I made the reservation) to see my recent made reservation.

I've tried to remember the id selected day and pass it through the activities and pass it back to the WeekReservations activity. But this gave me an error. because if it's the first time landing on this page there won't be anything to pass to this WeekReservations activity.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to remember which day the user has selected (to make a reservation) and show this selected day with list of reservations after the refresh?

If it's still unclear what I'm asking or lacking details, please feel free to point that out. I'll do my best to explain myself

---

**UPDATE**

Below is my code how I did it until now:

**WeekViewActivity.cs**

Code for choosing a day and show the listview and making a reservation

```
namespace iChargeClassTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "WeekViewActivity", Theme =     "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]          
    public class WeekViewActivity : Activity
{
    List<WeekReservationClass> result;
    string myCPID;
    string myCPAddress;

    TextView showDay1, showDay2, showDay3, showDay4, showDay5, showDay6, showDay7, selectedDay;
    Button makeBooking;

    int totalDays;
    DateTime chosenDateCP;
    List<WeekReservationClass> newList = new List<WeekReservationClass> ();

    private List<ReservationTime> myItems;
    private ListView mListView;

    protected async override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.WeekViewLayout);

        TextView showCurrentMonth = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtCurrentMonth);
        showCurrentMonth.Text = DateTime.Now.ToMonthName ();

        showDay1 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtToday);
        showDay2 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDay2);
        showDay3 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDay3);
        showDay4 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDay4);
        showDay5 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDay5);
        showDay6 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDay6);
        showDay7 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtDay7);

        makeBooking = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnBooking);

        selectedDay = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtSelectedDay);

        showDay1.Text = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString ();
        showDay2.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays (1).Day.ToString ();
        showDay3.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays (2).Day.ToString ();
        showDay4.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays (3).Day.ToString ();
        showDay5.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays (4).Day.ToString ();
        showDay6.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays (5).Day.ToString ();
        showDay7.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays (6).Day.ToString ();

        mListView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.myListView);
        myItems = new List<ReservationTime> ();

        myCPID = Settings.CharchingPoint_ID;
        myCPAddress = Settings.CharchingPointAddress;
        selectedDay.Text = myCPAddress;

        //get all the reservations from webservice
        try {
            string pathUrl = "reservations/weekReservations/";
            string currentToken = Settings.Token;

            var getResponse = await RequestClass.GetData (pathUrl, currentToken);

            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeekReservationClass>> (getResponse);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Check error: " + ex);
        }

        showDay1.Click += ShowDay1_Click;
        showDay2.Click += ShowDay2_Click;
        showDay3.Click += ShowDay3_Click;
        showDay4.Click += ShowDay4_Click;
        showDay5.Click += ShowDay5_Click;
        showDay6.Click += ShowDay6_Click;
        showDay7.Click += ShowDay7_Click;

        makeBooking.Click += MakeBooking_Click;
    }

    void MakeBooking_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.ChosenReservationDate = chosenDateCP.ToString ();
        Settings.CharchingPoint_ID = myCPID;
        StartActivity (typeof(ReservationHoursActivity));
    }

    //get and show reservation in listview
    void ShowDay7_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totalDays = int.Parse (showDay7.Text) - DateTime.Today.Day;
        chosenDateCP = DateTime.Today.AddDays (totalDays);

        myItems.Clear ();
        newList.Clear ();
        mListView.Adapter = null;

        //loop through json to get only reservation for day 7
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToDateTime (result [i].startTime));

            if (Convert.ToDateTime (result [i].startTime).Date == chosenDateCP.Date && result [i].chargingPointID == myCPID) {

                var newReservation = new WeekReservationClass ();

                newReservation._id = result [i]._id;
                newReservation.endTime = result [i].endTime;
                newReservation.startTime = result [i].startTime;
                newReservation.chargingPointID = result [i].chargingPointID;
                newReservation.userID = result [i].userID;
                newReservation.__v = result [i].__v;
                newReservation.modified_at = result [i].modified_at;
                newReservation.created_at = result [i].created_at;

                newList.Add (newReservation);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("failed");
            }
        }

        //loop through filtered list and show in listview
        for (int j = 0; j < newList.Count; j++) {
            Console.WriteLine (newList [j].startTime);
            myItems.Add (new ReservationTime () {
                StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime (newList [j].startTime), EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime (newList [j].endTime)
            });
        }
        MyListViewAdapter myadapter = new MyListViewAdapter (this, myItems);

        if (myadapter.IsEmpty) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "There are no reservations for today", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        } else {
            mListView.Adapter = myadapter;
        }

    }

    void ShowDay6_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totalDays = int.Parse (showDay6.Text) - DateTime.Today.Day;
        chosenDateCP = DateTime.Today.AddDays (totalDays);

        myItems.Clear ();
        newList.Clear ();
        mListView.Adapter = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToDateTime (result [i].startTime));
            if (Convert.ToDateTime (result [i].startTime).Date == chosenDateCP.Date && result [i].chargingPointID == myCPID) {

                var newReservation = new WeekReservationClass ();

                newReservation._id = result [i]._id;
                newReservation.endTime = result [i].endTime;
                newReservation.startTime = result [i].startTime;
                newReservation.chargingPointID = result [i].chargingPointID;
                newReservation.userID = result [i].userID;
                newReservation.__v = result [i].__v;
                newReservation.modified_at = result [i].modified_at;
                newReservation.created_at = result [i].created_at;

                newList.Add (newReservation);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("failed");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < newList.Count; j++) {
            Console.WriteLine (newList [j].startTime);
            myItems.Add (new ReservationTime () {
                StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime (newList [j].startTime), EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime (newList [j].endTime)
            });
        }
        MyListViewAdapter myadapter = new MyListViewAdapter (this, myItems);

        if (myadapter.IsEmpty) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "There are no reservations for today", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        } else {
            mListView.Adapter = myadapter;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**ReservationHoursActivity.cs**

Code for making a reservation and submit it to the webwervice

```
namespace iChargeClassTest
{
[Activity (Label = "ReservationHoursActivity", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]          
public class ReservationHoursActivity : Activity, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener
{
    string myDate;
    string myCP_ID;
    string selectedButtonDate;

    Button submitButtonMyslot;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.ReservationHoursLayout);

        myDate = Settings.ChosenReservationDate;
        myCP_ID = Settings.CharchingPoint_ID;

        submitButtonMyslot = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnSubmitSlot);
        submitButtonMyslot.Click += SubmitButtonMyslot_Click;

        /*
        Code for time picker
        */
    }

    /*
        methodes for time picker
    */

    //submit reservation
    async void SubmitButtonMyslot_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //post submitted data to webservice
        try {
            string stringDateTimeEND = Convert.ToDateTime (myDate).ToShortDateString () + " " + Convert.ToDateTime (time_display_End.Text).ToLongTimeString ();
            string stringDateTimeSTART = Convert.ToDateTime (myDate).ToShortDateString () + " " + Convert.ToDateTime (time_display_Start.Text).ToLongTimeString ();

            DateTime dtEnd = Convert.ToDateTime (stringDateTimeEND);
            DateTime dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime (stringDateTimeSTART);

            string utcEnd = dtEnd.ToUniversalTime ().ToString ("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
            string utcStart = dtStart.ToUniversalTime ().ToString ("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");

            var postData = "endTime=" + utcEnd;
            postData += "&startTime=" + utcStart;
            postData += "&chargingPointID=" + myCP_ID;
            postData += "&userID=" + Settings.User_ID;

            string pathUrl = "reservations/add";

            var post_response = await RequestClass.PostData (postData, pathUrl, Settings.Token);

            Toast.MakeText (this, "Your Booking is succefully send!", ToastLength.Long).Show ();

            //restart weekactivity to refresh
            var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(WeekViewActivity));
            intent.SetFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            StartActivity (intent);

            Finish ();//close the reservationHoursActivity

        } catch (WebException exception) {
            string responseText;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader (exception.Response.GetResponseStream ())) {
                responseText = reader.ReadToEnd ();
                Console.WriteLine (responseText);
            }
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Reservation Failed!", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It sounds like this is mostly working like you want, you just need to handle the case where the value is null because it's the first visit.  If you could post the relevant code we could give you more direction about handling that case.

Comment: @Jason I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't restart the activity after adding a new reservation. You should be opening the "New reservation" activity with `StartActivityForResult`, then handling a returned value in the `OnActivityResult` override method.

You wouldn't need to actually return anything, just an OK result would let you know to refresh the data(the user cancelling the add would return a Cancel result).

So something like...

```
private void AddReservationButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(AddReservationActivity));
     StartActivityForResult(intent, 1000); // 1000 is just a random number, though it needs to match the value in OnActivityResult
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
     if (resultCode == Result.Cancelled)
     {
        // user cancelled the reservation add, so don't refresh
        return;
     }

     if (requestCode == 1000)
     {
         RefreshReservationData();
     }
}
```

This would avoid having the recreate the Activity, which would probably save on memory. It would also fix your issue of remembering the day that was chosen as that day would still be chosen.

This is the typical way of a child activity letting a parent activity know that it's done something.

Comment: What you mean is refreshing the listview only when data is changed? But in my case, the data will be get when the user lands on the page and not when I choose a day. So in other words, the listview won't update if i don't refresh the activity itself :/
I've updated my post with more code for better understading

Comment: IMO, getting ALL of the reservations at one time, then showing only the ones necessary isn't a great architecture. However, if you want to keep it that way, then you have a couple of options. You can store the date in a global variable somewhere(like the `Settings` class you already have). Another option is to pass the date with the intent to the 'ReservationHoursActivity' activity. Then when you are ready to recreate the `WeekViewActivity`, pass the date again using the Intent. In the `OnCreate`, you can check if the date is in the intent. If it is, use it, if it's not, do the default

Comment: May I ask why you think it's not a good architecture? Wouldn't it be too much if I need to do a get call each  time the user choose another day? Wouldn't it be using too much of data bundle of the users internet?

Comment: Let's say that there are 50 reservations across 13 days. Currently, you get all 50. If you changed the architecture to just getting the reservations for the selected day, and the user only clicked on 4 days, that's WAY less data. Also, the time for the API call and the time to process the API data will be less because it's less data. I implemented a similar "date slider" using my architecture, and there is barely a blip in the UI. It loads fast enough that the user can quickly click on days and not see any noticable hiccup in performance.